# redirect all oldomain.com/* to new domain along with www/https

Tags: .htaccess, redirect

OK question is - i have 2 domains set up to one page

turner.info.pl and turner.org.pl changed content of old page i want to achieve

`*.turner.info.pl/*` redirect to `http()s://turner.org.pl`

`*.turner.org.pl` redirect to `http()s://turner.org.pl`

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www\.)?turner.info\.pl$ [NC]
RewriteRule (.*) http()s://turner.org.pl/ [R=301,L]
```

//that should redirect all from info.pl to root of org.pl

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.(.*)$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://%1/$1 [R=301,L]
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]
```

so far it works partially - it redirect www/non www to http()s://turner.org.pl but it don't redirect  turner.info.pl/somepage to http()s:/turner.org.pl but to http()s:/turner.org.pl/somepage (resulting 404)

damn max 2 links :) ignore all () inside http()s - I put it to bypass link limit :)

Answer (score 0):

Ok by trials and error found the solution changed line 3

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www\.)?turner.info\.pl$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http()s://turner.org.pl/ [R=301,L]
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.(.*)$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://%1/$1 [R=301,L]
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]
```

and i had to put it before default wordpress rules 
omit() in http()s if you want to use it :)